# Writing ArcPy UpdateCursor based on row test?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm working on building a series of updates to street feature class based on fields inside the class. I was attempting to do this with update cursor to get better performance.

When the Streets_GC_FullName is null, the STREETS_NW_SLIPRD = 2 and STREETS_NW_RAMP=1, then change the Streetname field to "Exit Ramp"

The Cursor runs for a little while but then none of the rows are actually updated.
I had tried adding the print statment to see if it was stopping on those rows that matched, but none printed.

So I'm assuming that my row test is failing?

```
fc = r'C:\GIS\Sept2018_MergeLA.gdb\NW_GC'
fields = ['Streets_GC_FULLNAME', 'Streets_NW_FEATTYP', 'Streets_NW_SLIPRD', 'Streets_NW_RAMP', 'StreetName','Streets_NW_ID']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if (row[0] is None and row[3] == 2 and row[4] == 1):
            row[5] == "Exit Ramp"
            # print("Updated"+row[6])
            cursor.updateRow(row)
print ("Processing complete")
```

Comment: It sounds like you have no rows where `row[0] is None and row[3] == 2 and row[4] == 1`.  Try printing row[0], row[3] and row[4] just before you test to see if you can spot any rows that should meet the criteria.  If you have many thousands to check then just add a where clause like OBJECTID < 10 onto your cursor to keep the output manageable.

Comment: row[0] is None should be row[0] == None, though depending on how your fields are populated blank may not be None (Null), check also row[0] == 0 or row[0] == '' depending on your field type.

Comment: For this test I have 2460 fields out of close to 1 million, that show up when doing arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("NW_GC", "SUBSET_SELECTION", "Streets_GC_FULLNAME IS NULL And Streets_NW_SLIPRD = 2 And Streets_NW_RAMP = 1", None)

Comment: You could create a selection on your layer or supply the query in the update cursor.. if you're creating a selection you should be able to use int(arcpy.GetCount_management("NW_GC").getOutput(0)) to tell if you've got any features that satisfy the query.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I was wondering about that, PyCharm was showing a syntax error if i use row[0] == None; although I have run it both ways to try to rule that out.  same thing ( no update) when i do row[0]== ''

Comment: What do you get when you print the updated row? If you're running from the toolbox you may need to use arcpy.AddMessage("Updated {}".format(row[6])) to get the message to show up in the tool dialog - also works in CMD and from the python console.

Comment: @Michael_Stimson...  The official 'Style Guide for Python' states "Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators".  See:  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three problems with your code that I can see:

**PROBLEM 1:**

The line `row[5] == "Exit Ramp"` should use `=` (assign a value) not `==` (testing for equality).  `row[5]` is not actually being assigned a value by the statement as it is.  In fact nothing at all is being done by that statement.

**PROBLEM 2:**

Your `row` indexes appear to be a bit muddled.  You have 6 fields in your cursor.  They are zero-indexed so the last field is `row[5]`, not `row[6]`.  So I would expect that the (commented out) `print` statement would crash if uncommented (and processing actually reached that point).

Your fields are:

```
fields = ['Streets_GC_FULLNAME', 'Streets_NW_FEATTYP', 'Streets_NW_SLIPRD', 'Streets_NW_RAMP', 'StreetName','Streets_NW_ID']
```

So...

- `row[0]` is `'Streets_GC_FULLNAME'`
- `row[1]` is `'Streets_NW_FEATTYP'`
- `row[2]` is `'Streets_NW_SLIPRD'`
- `row[3]` is `'Streets_NW_RAMP'`
- `row[4]` is `'StreetName'`
- `row[5]` is `'Streets_NW_ID'`
- `row[6]` DOES NOT EXIST and is an out-of-range index

So your `if` statement translates to something like:

```
if (Streets_GC_FULLNAME is None and Streets_NW_RAMP == 2 and StreetName == 1)
```

Do you really have any features with `StreetName == 1` ?  I would guess that `StreetName` is a string, so testing for equality with 1 is probably not what you really want.

**PROBLEM 3:**

Assuming problem 1 gets fixed...

Similarly, `row[5] = "Exit Ramp"` (single '=') would translate to something like `Streets_NW_ID = "Exit Ramp"`

From your question, I don't think this is what you intended.

**Solution:**

You said in your question that you wanted to test for:

> Streets_GC_FullName is null, the STREETS_NW_SLIPRD = 2 and STREETS_NW_RAMP=1, then change the Streetname field to "Exit Ramp"

This should be something like (untested):

```
        if row[0] is None and row[2] == 2 and row[3] == 1
            row[4] = "Exit Ramp"
            print "Updated {}".format(row[5])
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank You... The root of all of my problems was my muddled indexes.  I kept counting from 1 instead of 0 and getting my fields confused.  After resolving the indexes everything is good.   What i was trying to do was update the StreetName field to Exit Ramp not test that particular field.